# Why has a comment gone away after I accepted a suggestion for duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-comments

Someone (I suspect that this was [Mike McKerns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2379433/mike-mckerns)) left a very useful comment to a [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506707/how-to-find-out-what-cannot-be-serialized) and (I believe) marked the question as duplicate. His comment used to be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506707/how-to-find-out-what-cannot-be-serialized?noredirect=1#comment53006880_32506707).

Right after clicking "Does this solve your problem?" (and thus marking the question as indeed being a duplicate), his comment vanished (right after = a nanosecond after, this could not have been a coincidence).

Why has the comment disappeared? Is it linked to the fact that it was motioning it is a duplicate? Should it have disappeared even if it contained extra information (beside the "possibly a duplicate of ...")?

Comment: Yes; comments that were automatically generated by duplicate votes are scrubbed once the closure follows through. This happens even if the generated comments were edited after the fact to include more information. As to whether this behavior should change, I dunno.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment was auto-deleted when the question was closed, because it contained the same link as the dupe target. The automatic deletion does not discriminate based on extra information, it would be *extremely* hard for the deletion code to differentiate between *the commenter corrected a typo* and *added useful information*, so the script doesn't even try.

I've restored the comment sans the duplicate link.